# 3 level CSS3-only menu not opening 3rd level

Tags: html, css

Trying to create a 3 level menu using only HTML and CSS. I'm able to get it to display the 2nd level when I click on the first level but when I click on anything in 2nd level it just closes the menu. I've been able to also get it so when I click on 1st level it opens 2nd and 3rd levels at same time for the option I click.

I'm just beginning in CSS so please offer any constructive criticism you can. I'm sure this is something simple I'm missing. Don't want to use js for it.(learning that soon) Can someone take a look at it please?

Here's the HTML

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul class="show-menu">
        <li id="weekdays">
            <a href="#weekdays">Weekday Programming</a>
            <ul class="wd-menu">
                <li><a href="#">The Bigg Nez Show (M-F 9-noon)</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">The Rob Kaufman Show (M-F 4-7)</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">The Void w/Sabrina Boyd (Tu/Th 12-2p)</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">The Menace's Attic (Mon 2-4p)</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">DigBoston Presents (Tue 2-4p)</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">The Good American (Fri 2-4p)</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="weeknights">
            <a href="#weeknights">Weeknight Programming</a>
            <ul class="wn-menu">
                <li><a href="#monday">Monday</a></li>
                <ul class="three-line">
                    <li><a href="#">The Anthony Duva Show</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">The Adult Entertainment Show</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GeekBeat Radio</a></li>
                </ul>
                <li><a href="#tuesday">Tuesday</a></li>
                <ul class="two-line">
                    <li><a href="#">Spin City</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Three Strange Women</a></li>
                </ul>
                <li><a href="#wednesday">Wednesday</a></li>
                <ul class="two-line">
                    <li><a href="#">The Chicken Spot</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Saucy Entertainment</a></li>
                </ul>
                <li><a href="#thursday">Thursday</a></li>
                <ul class="three-line">
                    <li><a href="#">Banned in Boston</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Organized Nonsense</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">The D-Pad</a></li>
                </ul>
                <li><a href="#friday">Friday</a></li>
                <ul class="three-line">
                     <li><a href="#">Beats, Rhymes &#38; Life</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">The Living Room</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">3&#39;s Company</a></li>
                </ul>                   
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="weekends">
            <a href="#weekends">Weekend Programming</a>
            <ul class="we-menu">
        <div id="saturday">    
                <li><a href="#saturday">Saturday</a></li>
            <ul class="eight-line">
                 <li><a href="#">Boston Pot Report</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Blues &#38; Beyond</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Two Hotheads</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Citywide Blackout</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Boston Shit Show</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Bottoms Up</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Radio Remi</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">The DJ Hothands Hour</a></li>
            </ul> 
        <div id="sunday">
                <li><a href="#sunday">Sunday</a></li>
            <ul class="six-line">
                 <li><a href="#">Keeping it Latin</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Shady Lady Sports Show</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">The Audio Spectrum</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">The Lifestyles Show</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">The Foundation</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Sterlingtology</a></li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<!--end accordian-->
```

And here is the CSS:

```
    #menu { width:250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* clearing */

.show-menu,
.show-menu ul,
.show-menu li,
.show-menu a,
.show-menu span {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
}

.show-menu li {
    list-style: none;
}

/* main menu style */

.show-menu li > a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    height:28px;

    color: #FFFFFF;
    font: bold 11px/28px Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;


    background: #343435;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #343435 1%, #4a4a4a 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#343435), color-stop(100%,#4a4a4a));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #343435 1%,#4a4a4a 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #343435 1%,#4a4a4a 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #343435 1%,#4a4a4a 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #343435 1%,#4a4a4a 100%);

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
}

.show-menu > li:hover > a {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .2);


    background: #F0EF8A;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%, #BFBFBF 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#F0EF8A), color-stop(100%,#BFBFBF));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%,#BFBFBF 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%,#BFBFBF 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%,#BFBFBF 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%,#BFBFBF 100%);


    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);

}

/* weekday style */

.wd-menu li a {
    color: #333333;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .2);
    text-align: left;
    background: #D7D3D3;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c1bfbf;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
}

.wd-menu li:hover a {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .2);


    background: #F0EF8A;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%, #BFBFBF 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#F0EF8A), color-stop(100%,#BFBFBF));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%,#BFBFBF 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%,#BFBFBF 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%,#BFBFBF 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%,#BFBFBF 100%);


    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
}


/* weeknight style */

.wn-menu li a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .2);
    text-align: left;
    background: #666666;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c1bfbf;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
}

.wn-menu li:hover a {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .2);


    background: #F0EF8A;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%, #BFBFBF 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#F0EF8A), color-stop(100%,#BFBFBF));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%,#BFBFBF 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%,#BFBFBF 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%,#BFBFBF 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%,#BFBFBF 100%);


    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
 }
/* weekend style */

.we-menu li a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .2);
    text-align: left;
    background: #666666;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c1bfbf;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
 }

.we-menu li:hover a {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .2);


    background: #F0EF8A;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%, #BFBFBF 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#F0EF8A), color-stop(100%,#BFBFBF));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%,#BFBFBF 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%,#BFBFBF 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%,#BFBFBF 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%,#BFBFBF 100%);


    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
}

/* two-line style */

.two-line li a {
    color: #333333;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .2);
    text-align: left;
    background: #D7D3D3;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c1bfbf;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
}

.two-line li:hover a {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .2);


    background: #F0EF8A;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%, #BFBFBF 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#F0EF8A), color-stop(100%,#BFBFBF));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%,#BFBFBF 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%,#BFBFBF 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%,#BFBFBF 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%,#BFBFBF 100%);


    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
}
/* three-line style */

.three-line li a {
    color: #333333;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .2);
    text-align: left;
    background: #D7D3D3;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c1bfbf;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
}

.three-line li:hover a {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .2);


    background: #F0EF8A;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%, #BFBFBF 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#F0EF8A), color-stop(100%,#BFBFBF));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%,#BFBFBF 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%,#BFBFBF 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%,#BFBFBF 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%,#BFBFBF 100%);


    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
}

/* six-line style */

.six-line li a {
    color: #333333;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .2);
    text-align: left;
    background: #D7D3D3;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c1bfbf;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
}

.six-line li:hover a {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .2);


    background: #F0EF8A;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%, #BFBFBF 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#F0EF8A), color-stop(100%,#BFBFBF));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%,#BFBFBF 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%,#BFBFBF 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%,#BFBFBF 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%,#BFBFBF 100%);


    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
}

 /* eight-line style */

.eight-line li a {
    color: #333333;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .2);
    text-align: left;
    background: #D7D3D3;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c1bfbf;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
}

.eight-line li:hover a {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .2);


    background: #F0EF8A;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%, #BFBFBF 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#F0EF8A), color-stop(100%,#BFBFBF));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%,#BFBFBF 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%,#BFBFBF 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%,#BFBFBF 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #F0EF8A 1%,#BFBFBF 100%);


    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
}



/* weekday accordion action */

.show-menu li > .wd-menu {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;

    -webkit-transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
}


.show-menu li:target > .wd-menu {
    height: auto;
}

/* weeknight accordion action */
.show-menu li > .wn-menu {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;

    -webkit-transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
}

.show-menu li:target > .wn-menu {
    height: auto;
}

/* weekend accordion action */
.show-menu li > .we-menu {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;

    -webkit-transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
}

.show-menu li:target > .we-menu {
    height: auto;
}

/* two-line accordion action */
.two-line {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;

    -webkit-transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
}

.show-menu li:target > .two-line {
    height: auto;
}

/* three-line accordion action */
.three-line {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;

    -webkit-transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
}

.show-menu li:target > .three-line {
    height: auto;
}

/* six-line accordion action */
.six-line {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;

    -webkit-transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
}

.we-menu li:target > .six-line {
    height: auto;
}

/* eight-line accordion action */
.eight-line {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;

    -webkit-transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
}

 .we-menu li:target > .eight-line {
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: You pasted quite a bit of code, maybe you should try excerpting the key parts that demonstrate the error instead for ease of debugging.

Comment: Here is the code in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4cd8t/

Comment: You have some invalid HTML, possibly due to a copy/paste SNAFU. Update this fiddle with valid code, then add a link to the updated version to your answer. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/SsQgf

Comment: .. need to ... kill the urge .. to .. indent code.

Comment: @MilchePatern TidyUp in jsFiddle works well.

Answer (score 0):

Your markups are messed up.

Start with a valid html coding :

```
<a href="#weeknights">Weeknight Programming</a>
        <ul class="wn-menu">
            <li><a href="#monday">Monday</a></li>

    /* this next block is not well nested  */
            <ul class="three-line">
             <li><a href="#">The Anthony Duva Show</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">The Adult Entertainment Show</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">GeekBeat Radio</a></li>
        </ul>
        <li><a href="#tuesday">Tuesday</  etc.etc etc.
```

Revise your code to correctly nest ul > li ( ul > li > div, ul > li > ul > li ) and make sure your tags are closed properly.

**Then**, maybe your .css+javascript will work.